# Windows 2016 64 bit not boot up and raises error about tm.sys. What should I do?

Tags: boot, windows-server-2016

We have several windows 2016 servers and one of them started to act strangely (started to show nonsense characters in start menu, iis errors, network errors, etc...)

So I rebooted it normally. (Not forced or hardware initiated, I used shut down options of windows to reboot.)

Windows couldn't started and stuck in auto repair loop.

I disabled the auto repair function and now I can see the error.

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

It gives an error about tm.sys (upgrading bios now so I can not provide error code right now but I will when I can asap)

I tried these in command prompt from troubleshoot screen, but no luck:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

I plan to repair windows installation by booting up from installation dvd.

What do you suggest me to do?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I replaced windows\system32\drivers\tm.sys with the tm.sys from installation dvd and then it started to give error about ksecpkg.sys. I replaced that file too and windows started successfully but after several seconds after login, it crashes.

What should I do now?

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like maybe filesystem or harddrive error. Figure out underlying course by doing filesystem and HDD scans, and make sure backups are recent.

Comment: @mzhaase what commands you suggest to run? and btw, is there a way to check registry records if there are problems?

Comment: @mzhaase when I run chkdsk /f it can not find any problems. Any additional command suggestions?

Comment: You could try sfc /scannow but it probably won't finish. There must be a reason the system files are broken.

Comment: I dont think that it is hdd failure because we have raid-5 with 4 disks active and 1 spare. Memory diagnostics clear and this server was running almost a year without a single failure. After I changed tm.sys and ksecpkg.sys files, I noticed that it crashes after network status becomes connected. Services can not start btw (even event logging)

Comment: It turns out that one of disks in raid-5 configuration is failed and that caused files to be broken. This is bad. We reinstalled windows and it is working now but we have a huge problem with data files, we are checking all and fixing the corrupted files one by one right now. Thank you all for your help to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare HDD I would spin up a fresh copy of Server 2016 on spare / replacement drive and see if the same issues occur. If not then it points towards a Disk issue. If you still see issues they you have some more major Hardware issue.